# Use CSS preprocessor on CKEditor 4 contextmenu

Tags: wysiwyg

I had to customize the look and feel of the CKEditor 4 context menu for our (internal use only) module. So, I copied `core/assets/vendor/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css` to `my_module/css/contextmenu.css`, I changed it to my liking, and then I added the following line in `src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin/CustomInternal.php`:

```
    $config['contextmenu_contentsCss'] = '/CLS/modules/custom/my_module/css/contextmenu.css' ;
```

This works, but since the menu is in a `iframe` of its own if I change the css it's very hard to pick up the new version, even with `Ctrl-F5`.

In production I never have problems with changes to CSS or JS because the preprocessor generates unique names of the processed files at every change. Can I use it to manage this file, somehow? I suppose I'd have to make the source CSS file visible to the preprocessor, get the name of the processed file, and then add it dynamically to the CKEditor configuration... not so simple, I guess. Any better idea?